# Gave incorrect answers after calculate using an array numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Following code gave an incorrect answers. What is a best way to correct it?  I am new to programming.

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] array = new double[] {5, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6};
    double t= 6.4;  

    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; ++k){
      double d= array[k]-t;
      System.out.println("d is="+d); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It gave following answers,                                                                                                   d is=-1.4000000000000004
d is=-2.4000000000000004
d is=-0.40000000000000036
d is=0.5999999999999996
d is=0.5999999999999996
d is=-0.40000000000000036                                                                                               But correct answers should be,                                                                                               d is=-1.4
d is=-2.4
d is=-0.4
d is=-0.4
d is=0.6
d is=0.6
d is=-0.4

Comment: try debugging the code, you'll know how, why and where the values are being assigned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)